# Django doesn’t detect change in migrations

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-migrations

I have a Django app and i added my migrations folders to gitignore file and migrated for the first time then i added a field user model and migrated again. all of migration process happened again but in migration Django didn’t apply the change. what should i do to apply my changes to the database without having to push the migrations folder to the server

Answer (score 0):

In case you are only running `python manage.py migrate` on the server then you **have to push** the migrations folder.

But if you are running both `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` on the server. Then you can get away with only pushing your migration folder with a file named `__init__.py`.

You can refer to the suggested workflow from django documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/migrations/#workflow).